# How can I create a table view of percentiles by date using Python

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-groupby, quantile

Using `Python/Jupyter Notebook` I'd like to create a table view of percentiles `grouped by date`.

The data set looks something like this:

```
count date
12    2020-02-01
15    2020-02-01
20    2020-02-02
...
```

and the outcome I'm looking for looks something like this:

```
      2020-02-01   2020-02-02
25%     12.5           15        
50%     15             16
75%     17.5           17
95%     19             18.5
```

I've seen the `quantile` function but not sure how to arrange it in a table view.

Answer (score 1):

Use [`DataFrameGroupBy.quantile`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.quantile.html) with [`DataFrame.unstack`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.unstack.html) - last data cleaning - remove columns name by [`DataFrame.rename_axis`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.rename_axis.html) and dynamic convert percentiles to percentages by `f-string`s:

```
df = (df.groupby('date')['count']
        .quantile([.25,.5,.75,.95])
        .unstack(0)
        .rename_axis(None, axis=1)
        .rename(lambda x: f'{int(x * 100)}%'))

print (df)
     2020-02-01  2020-02-02
25%       12.75        20.0
50%       13.50        20.0
75%       14.25        20.0
95%       14.85        20.0
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also use [.describe()](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.describe.html)

```
import pandas as pd 

# Creating the dataframe  
df = pd.DataFrame({"count":[12, 15, 20],
                   "date":['2020-02-01', '2020-02-01', '2020-02-02']})

df2 = df.groupby('date')['count'].describe(percentiles=[.25, .5, .75, .95])

# Filtering out the needed columns
df2 = df2[['25%', '50%', '75%', '95%']].T

# output
date  2020-02-01  2020-02-02
25%        12.75        20.0
50%        13.50        20.0
75%        14.25        20.0
95%        14.85        20.0
```